# Normal distribution - Marginalization $P(x)$ given $P(z)$ and $P(x\mid z)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I'm trying to get $P(x)$ given $P(z)$ and $P(x\mid z)$.
I tried doing P(x) = P(x|z)P(z) but I didn't manage to arrive at the correct result.

$P(z) = N(z\mid 0, I)$

$P(x\mid z) = N(x\mid Wz+ \mu, \phi)$

And the given solution for $P(x)$ is $N(\mu, WW^T + \phi)$.

Is it correct assuming $P(x) = P(x) = P(x\mid z)P(z)$?
Otherwise, how would we get $P(x)$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Yes but you also divide by normalisation factor $\int P(x|z)P(z)$.